# How to track frames from tf in ROS

Tags: ros, frames, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner in using ROS. I am trying to track some frames that are published as a set of transform but I do not know how to do this. I would like to ask if anyone that knows how to track frames on ROS can help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258477/how-to-track-frames-from-tf-in-ros/) by [Glass_Eater](https://answers.ros.org/users/29913/glass_eater/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regardless of whether you are in C++ or Python, you will want to create a tf listener object. Then you can repeatedly lookup the transform between two frames that you are interested in tracking. This looked-up transform will contain a position and quaternion that represents the transformation between the two frames of interest. Many tutorials on the wiki will use the original tf API, but these days it is probably better to use the tf2 API. See the following tutorials:

- [Writing a tf2 listener Python](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28Python%29)
- [Writing a tf2 listener C++](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29)

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0